# How to get a row from a database (SQLite3) into a string from Julia?

Tags: sqlite, julia

**Julia, SQLite3**

Hi! I have an SQLite3 database and want to get information from it into a string, **not** DataFrame.

```
# Connection to database
db = SQLite.DB(raw"pictures.sqlite")
# Creation of table
SQLite.execute(db, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Files")
SQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Files
                            (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
                            FullName TEXT,
                            creation_date TEXT,
                            change_date TEXT,
                            size  INTEGER,
                            UNIQUE (ID))")
#Another code
#This is a way to add rows to database (it works)
DBInterface.execute(db, 
            "INSERT INTO Files (FullName, creation_date, change_date, size) 
            VALUES
            ('$fileName', '$cdate', '$mdate', '$fileSize')
        ")
#Then i am trying to get one row into a string
strq = SQLite.DBInterface.execute(db, "SELECT * FROM Files WHERE ID=3")
#I can't transfornm these to string
```

I'm writing on **Julia** and need help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR:

```
CSV.write(stdout, strq);
```

#### Explanation

The API of SQLite.jl assumes using `DBInterface.execute` for querying the database.
This method yields an object of type `SQLite.Query`.

Let's have a look what can we do with it:

```
julia> methodswith(SQLite.Query, supertypes=true)
[1] eltype(q::SQLite.Query) in SQLite at ~/.julia/packages/SQLite/wpQeE/src/tables.jl:51
[2] isempty(q::SQLite.Query) in SQLite at ~/.julia/packages/SQLite/wpQeE/src/tables.jl:15
[3] iterate(q::SQLite.Query) in SQLite at ~/.julia/packages/SQLite/wpQeE/src/tables.jl:94
[4] iterate(q::SQLite.Query, rownumber) in SQLite at ~/.julia/packages/SQLite/wpQeE/src/tables.jl:100
```

You can see one important thing - you can do whatever you want with `SQLite.Query` as long as it matches the `Tables.jl` interfaces. So you are not obliged to use `DataFrames` but there is no "pure string" implementation, such thing would not make any sense neither.

However, there are many interfaces for Tables. The one you need is `CSV.jl` will exactly give you something like "string representation" of your SQL table.

Try this with your code (I inserted one row to my table to see the results):

```
julia> CSV.write(stdout, strq);
ID,FullName,creation_date,change_date,size
1,somefilename,somecdate,somemfate,0
```

Comment: Thanks for yor answer!! And can I ask another small question? How to export a string (or array) from CSV file using CSV.jl package?

Comment: Also what type is "stdout" then? It is not readable.

Comment: `stdout` represents the standard output stream - to find `typeof(stdout)`its type. Instead of `stdout` you could give a `String` with a file path - in that case the output would get saved to a file.

Comment: Thank you very much! You solved my problem. May be you can advise an easy method to  get the number of rows in database? I don't know how to do it using julia. Only with the help of SQL query?

Comment: You need to do `SELECT count(*) FROM table`. If you have a `DataFrame` you can of course query the number of rows but this obviously would require sending all data from the database to Julia

Comment: While working with CSV file, i am trying to read it and write into it a few times and have an ERROR: SystemError: opening file "path-to-file": Invalid argument. Why can it be?

Comment: Can you have a look at my question "Getting an error while reading CSV file and writing into it using Julia"?

Comment: sure as soon as you provide the MWE